# С++ ООП. Множественное наследование

Tags: c++, ооп

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить проблему. У меня есть код, в который подается идентификатор, допустим Object.

Вывод должен выводить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class cl_1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_1(){}
    cl_1(string name) {
        this->name = name + "_1";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }
};

class cl_2 : virtual public cl_1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_2(string name) : cl_1(name + "_2") {
        this->name = name + "_2";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_3 : virtual  public cl_1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_3(string name) : cl_1(name + "_3") {
        this->name = name + "_3";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_4 : virtual public cl_1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_4(string name) : cl_1(name + "_4") {
        this->name = name + "_4";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_5 : virtual public cl_1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_5(string name) : cl_1(name + "_5") {
        this->name = name + "_5";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_6 : public cl_2, public cl_3 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_6(string name) : cl_1(name + "_6"), cl_2(name + "_6"), cl_3(name + "_6") {
        this->name = name + "_6";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_7 : public cl_4, public cl_5 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_7(string name) : cl_1(name + "_7"), cl_4(name + "_7"), cl_5(name + "_7") {
        this->name = name + "_7";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

class cl_8 : public cl_6, public cl_7 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    cl_8(string name) : cl_1(name + "_8"), cl_6(name + "_8"), cl_7(name + "_8") {
        this->name = name + "_8";
    }

    void get_name() {
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    string identifier;
    cin >> identifier;

    cl_8 obj8(identifier);
    cl_8* ptr = &obj8;
    ptr->cl_6::cl_2::cl_1::get_name(); // должно вывести "Object_8_6_2_1"
    ptr->cl_6::cl_3::cl_1::get_name(); // должно вывести "Object_8_6_3_1"
    ptr->cl_8::cl_1::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_1::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_6::cl_2::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_6::cl_3::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_7::cl_4::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_7::cl_5::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_6::get_name();
    ptr->cl_8::cl_7::get_name();
    ptr->get_name();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне просто интересно, а почему вы везде `cl_8` а в первых двух примерах нет) И 2 вопрос, а зачем вам в `cl_8(string name) : cl_1(name + "_8"), cl_6(name + "_8")` `cl_1` вот так делать?

Comment: Ну, т.к cl_8 - родительский класс, это для иницилизации дочерних классов cl_6 и cl_7, а cl_1 - базовый класс для cl_2, cl_3, cl_4, cl_5 и, в конце концов, для классов cl_6, cl_7 и cl_8. По идее, нет?

Comment: а почему вы тогда 2/3/4/5 не пишите? Вас не смущает это?

Comment: Но ведь 2,3,4,5 не наследники cl_8

Comment: так и 1 тоже. просто не прямой а через промежуточные. И ещё, вы по заданию должны мешать virtual и public?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно мешать

Comment: Но просто как я без виртуального класса смогу вывести Object_8_1. Если Cl_1 не прямой наследник Cl_8

Comment: Виртуальное наследование делает вызов конструктора cl_1 один раз и `cl_8(string name0) : cl_1(name0 + "_8")` именно это и делает. Это не проблема, так и должно быть. Если вы точно знаете, что должно быть по другому, то в вопросе укажите точное задание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш класс `cl_1` вы виртуально наследуете. Это значит, что его экземпляр существует в одном лице.
Вот как выглядит ваше дерево классов :

```
      - 1 -
    /  / \  \
  2   3   4   5
   \ /     \ /
    6       7
      \   /
        8
```

При вызове конструктора объекта cl_8

```cpp
cl_8(string name) : 
  cl_1(name + "_8"),
  cl_6(name + "_8"),
  cl_7(name + "_8")
```

Конструктор класса `cl_1` будет вызван **один** раз и как раз с таким именем `Object_8_1`.
*Имя в классе cl_1 физически не может иметь разные имена одновременно. Ни _8_6_2_1 .. ни _8_7_5_1 и т.д.*